# Couldn't or couldn't have in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> *You **couldn't have met** my grand mother; she died before you were born.*
>
> *You **couldn't meet** my grand mother; she died before you were born.*

Are these two sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: As a footnote, _grandmother_ is one word, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were going to do an oral history project, I would|should like to meet your grandmother.
>   --*You couldn't meet her. She is no longer alive.*
>
> I met your grandmother once, years ago.
>   -- *You couldn't have met her. She died before you were born.*
>
> I want to meet your grandmother.
>   --*You can't meet her. She is no longer alive.*

Comment: So my first sentence is about impossibility in the past and the second one is about inability in the past and both are correct?Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Your first one is about a past definite impossibility and your second one is idiomatic only in the context of an indefinite present or future.  It's not about a past inability or impossibility.